# NSPredicate Formatting Issue

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I'm creating an iOS app where I want the user to be able to search through a `UITableView` and display results based on a variety of different inputs. I'm using an NSPredicate with multiple conditions separated by "OR" to do this, but for some reason it's only searching with the first condition and none of the others.

Here's how my NSPredicate is formatted:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF.firstName CONTAINS[c]
%@) OR (SELF.lastName CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SELF.major CONTAINS[c] %@) OR
(SELF.year CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (SELF.gpa CONTAINS[c] %@)",
searchController.searchBar.text!)
```

My parameters are firstName, lastName, major, year, and gpa. When I type in anything besides the first name in the search bar, no results show up. But typing in a first name does indeed return matches. Why is this happening? Is my NSPredicate formatted incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let text = searchController.searchBar.text, text.characters.count > 0{
    var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "self.firstName CONTAINS[c]",text))
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "self.lastName CONTAINS[c]",text))
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "self.major CONTAINS[c]",text))
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "self.year CONTAINS[c]",text))
    predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "self.gpa CONTAINS[c]",text))

    let searchPredicate:NSPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have five instances of the `%@` format specifier in your predicate so you need to pass five values. You are only passing one.

You need to repeat `searchController.searchBar.text!` five times. BTW - assign that to a safely unwrapped variable and repeat that variable five times. It will be less typing.

```
if let srch = searchController.searchBar.text {
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF.firstName CONTAINS[c] %@) OR
        (SELF.lastName CONTAINS[c] %@) OR
        (SELF.major CONTAINS[c] %@) OR
        (SELF.year CONTAINS[c] %@) OR
        (SELF.gpa CONTAINS[c] %@)", srch, srch, srch, srch, srch)
    ...
}
```

Comment: NSPredicate does not support positional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should work and is probably the simplest syntax for Swift if all your subpredicates are the same:

```
if let text = searchController.searchBar.text {
    let myCompondPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: ["firstName", "lastName", "major", "year", "gpa"].map {
        NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", $0, text)
    })

    // Do something with myCompondPredicate here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple, static, predicate like this, I would opt for a native Swift approach:

```
import Foundation

struct Student {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let major: String
    let gpa: Double
}

extension Student {
    func anyFields(contain searchString: String) -> Bool {
        return firstName.contains(searchString)
            || lastName.contains(searchString)
            || major.contains(searchString)
            || String(gpa).contains(searchString)
    }

    // Alternate implementation:
    /* 
    func anyFields(contain searchString: String) -> Bool {
        return [firstName, lastName, major, String(gpa)].contains(where: { field in
            field.contains(searchString)
        })
    } */
}


let matchingStudents = students.filter(Student.anyFields(contain:))
```